# jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery

I have the jQuery Accordion set up on a page of mine, and the first div is automatically expanded.

Is there a way to have that first accordion closed on page load?

```
$(function() {
    $( '#accordion' ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
                    autoHeight:false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `active` option to `false`.

According to the docs:

> active - Selector for the active
>   element. Set to false to display none
>   at start. Needs collapsible: true.

Example:

```
$(function() {
    $( '#accordion' ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight:false,
        active:false
    });
});
```

You can see all the different options on the jQuery UI website. [Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) is the docs for the accordion widget.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
> active: false
```

to your option list, means it wont open until it is clicked.